# How can I pass IO into an elixir function that is passed into another function

Tags: elixir

I want to run a function in a certain directory, so I have this code:

```
  def main(args) do
    args |> directory |> File.cd!(&Cli.run/0) |> IO.puts
  end

  def directory([]) do
    "."
  end

  def directory(args) do
    hd(args)
  end
```

I now want to pass IO into Cli.run, so that I can test it - at the moment IO is just used directly in Cli.run.

How can I pass it in?

Comment: i'm not entirely sure what you are doing here. if you want to pass something (IO) throught to Cli.run, you would need to add it to the arguments of main `def main(args, io \\ IO) do ...` and then on to Cli.run `fn -> Cli.run(io) end`
if you want to check IO in tests, there is http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/ex_unit/ExUnit.CaptureIO.html#capture_io/1

Comment: Yes, passing the annonymous function `fn -> Cli.run(io) end` into `File.cd!` worked, thanks.

Comment: You should post the right solution as an answer so others who search for this question can easily find it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [manukall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5566876/manukall), the solution is to pass an anonymous function to `File.cd!` like this:

```
File.cd!(fn -> Openreevoo.Cli.run(IO) end)
```